# Defining a new instance over Yesod's Key a?

Tags: haskell, yesod, type-families

Having received a value of type `Key a`, I can easily define and use this function:

```
keyToInt64 :: Key a -> Int64
keyToInt64 (Key (PersistInt64 n)) = n
keyToInt64 _ = error "wrong database type"
```

However, I can't use the same function from within an instance for `Key a`!

```
instance Num (Key a) where
    fromInteger = fromIntegral . keyToInt64
```

I get this error:

```
Illegal type synonym family application in instance: Key a
In the instance declaration for `Num (Key a)'
```

How do I define this instance? Why doesn't my approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key entity`is a synonym for `KeyBackend backend entity`, so you need to define the instance on the concrete type.

```
instance Num (KeyBackend backend entity) where
  Key (PersistInt64 a) + Key (PersistInt64 b) = Key . PersistInt64 $ a + b
  Key _                + _                    = error "wrong database type"
  _                    + Key _                = error "wrong database type"
  ...
```

Though using `error` so gratuitously is likely to cause a lot of pain later.